# Bootstrap TableExport decimal issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, excel, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table displaying employee data, including the payroll ID which have the given format: 1606.xxxx

Here's what my table looks like :

```
<table id="table_search"
    data-toggle="table"
    data-search="true"
    data-show-refresh="true"
    data-show-toggle="true"
    data-show-columns="true"
    data-show-export="true"
    data-minimum-count-columns="2"
    data-show-pagination-switch="true"
    data-pagination="true"
    data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
    data-show-footer="false"
    data-export-data-type="all"
    data-export-types="['excel']">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">ID</th>
            <th data-field="payroll_id" >Payroll ID</th>
            <th data-field="nama_karyawan">Employee Name</th>
            <th data-field="level">Level</th>
            <th data-field="grade">Grade</th>
            <th data-field="title">Title</th>
            <th data-field="lokasi">Location</th>
            <th data-field="cost_sales">Cost Sales</th>
            <th data-field="dept">Department</th>
            <th data-field="div">Division</th>
            <th data-field="dir">Directorat</th>
            <th data-field="active_period">Active Period</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The table displays it correctly, however when I export it into excel using [TableExport](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/export.html) plugin it goes like this 
[exported results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sogIs.png)

As you can see, somehow the plugin treats it as a number with decimal, which is exactly what I am avoiding. I've tried commenting the parseNumber function which might be the cause in the tableExport js file, however the results always comes out the same

What am I doing wrong ?

**PS:** I don't want formatting after the file is exported, I want it to export the data as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
...
<td data-tableexport-msonumberformat="\@">123.450</td>
...
```

With this the `tableExport.js` will use `mso-number-format: "\@"` as `TD`style while creating the `HTML`Excel export. This results in formatting the cell as `Text`.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/uqtubq5c/1/

You could also use

```
...
<td data-tableexport-msonumberformat="0.000">123.450</td>
...
```

This leads to the number format `0.000` in Excel. So the cell content remains a number and will be useable in calculations further. The `Text` will possible lead to issues while used in calculations.

---

If you cannot set own `data-tableexport-msonumberformat` attributes to `TD` elements, then you could extend the `tableExport.jquery.plugin`.

In `tableExport.js` have:

```
...
      var defaults = {
        onMsoNumberFormat: onMsoNumberFormat,
...
```

`onMsoNumberFormat` must be a function.

If the function `onMsoNumberFormat` is like:

```
onMsoNumberFormat = function(cell, row, col) {
 if (row > 0 && col == 2) {
  return "#\\,##0\\.00";
 }
 if (row > 0 && col == 3) {
  return "\\@";
 }
};
```

then the third column (col==2) from row 2 (row>0) upwards will get `style="mso-number-format:#\,##0\.00"` and the fourth column (col==3) from row 2 (row>0) upwards will get `style="mso-number-format:\@"`. `@` is `Text`format.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/uqtubq5c/3/

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am populating the table using a JSON callback. I can't add a property to the td, because I am only defining the th.. (I already edited my question). I tried using jQuery's attr() method on the callback success, but I can't make it work

Comment: See my supplements.

Comment: You are a life saver ! This fiddle should be in the bootstrap table example page